# Python : BeautifulSoup4 Error scraping Wikipedia

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am new to web-scraping and python and I wanted to make a code that can scrape Wikipedia and make it quicker . In this you just have to type in the thing you wanna search for example “Clock” So it will got to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock and scrape it from there. If there is something other than this wrong please tell me.

[GitHub](https://github.com/fast-and-curious-1910/wiki-bot)

So when I run the code I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
    wikibot(url)
  File "main.py", line 25, in wikibot
    print(soup,('p')[i].text)
IndexError: string index out of range
```

And after this I want it to write this data to a text file , which I think can be done with

```
write()
```

the same way as

```
print()
```

I am following a tutorial and when he showed a demo it ran flawlessly with no errors. Is my code wrong or my packages are erroring out ?

Comment: if you are just running ```wikibot(url)```, there is a chance it is the package causing problem.

Comment: theres nothing in your details variable, you can always debug with print statements to check variables at different stages during the scraping

Comment: @Ironkey What do you mean ?

Comment: You really should include *your* code. And do you think **Python : BeautifulSoup4** is a good summary of your problem? Wouldn't **Error scraping Wikipedia with wikiibot** or something similar have been better? It's not too late ....

Comment: @Booboo I have added GitHub Links,

Comment: @Booboo GitHub links were present

Comment: What information do  you want to get from the page?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I want to get important stuff like capital , continent and evrything in that box along with the description on the top

Comment: Oh, I see that the GitHub code does the input.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the lines in the GitHub source:

```
for i in range(1,3):
    print(soup,('p')[i].text)
```

with:

```
paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
for paragraph in paragraphs:
    print(paragraph.text)
    print()
```

This will print all the paragraphs.

**Update: to write output to a file**

```
with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            f.write(paragraph.text)
            f.write('\n\n') # two newlines
```

Comment: I have changed it to write

Comment: And I get error :   File "main.py", line 35, in <module>
    f.write()
TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Comment: What are you trying to write to? If you want to do the equivalent of the above print yuu need to 1. `import sys` 2. `sys.stdout.write(paragraph.text + '\n') # must include explicitly the newline, which is automatically by default provided by print()`

Comment: Or if `f` is file you have opened, to write a single newline: `f.write('\n')` to replace `print()`. See updated answer for best approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract and print the text instead of the for loop use this:

```
print(soup.get_text())
```

For other methods and usages please check the doc: [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)